# Rails 4 - nested form not rendering in production mode

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I'm having an issue with a nested set of form fields not rendering in production mode. It all works fine in development mode.

In production mode, I get the link to add the address (which in turn reveals the form) but  when I click that link the page reloads, but the nested fields do not appear. When I use the chrome inspector, I can see all of the form html for the nested fields, they just aren't visible on the page.

My main form is:

```
<div class="row">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="intpol2">

                          Your addresss
                        </div>

                          <%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>
                            <%= render 'addresses/address_fields', f: f %>
                          <% end %>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                           <%= link_to_add_association 'Add an address', f, :addresses, partial: 'addresses/address_fields' %>

                        </div>

                      </div>

                    </div>
```

Can anyone think why the form would work properly in development mode but not in production mode?

There isn't any js and the form fields html file has:

```
<div class="nested-fields">

  <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <%= f.input :unit %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <%= f.input :street_number %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <%= f.input :street %>
                        </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <%= f.input :building %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <%= f.input :city %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                            <%= f.input :region %>
                        </div>
            </div>

                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <%= f.input :zip %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">

                <!--f.country_select(:country, {selected: @profile.country_name}, {class: "form-control"}) -->
              <%=   f.country_select  :country, priority: [ "Australia", "New Zealand", "United Kingdom" ]  %>

                    </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
              <%= f.input :time_zone %>
            </div>


           </div>

           <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <%= f.input :main_address %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :project_offsite %>
                    </div>
           </div>

           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>

            </div>
           </div>

         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= link_to_remove_association 'Remove this address', f %>
          </div>

        </div>
  </div>    
</div>

<div class = "debug" > <%= yield %> <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %></div>
```

Comment: Do you need to pass a variable to the partial?

Comment: Most likely your problem is related to your javascript. Please, add your rendered HTML link that shows your form and related javascript code.

Comment: @Uzbekjon - i added the form fields. There isn't any javascript that specifically targets this. i use cocoon gem to handle the nesting

Comment: Did you add `//= require cocoon` line to your `application.js` file?

Comment: Yes - I do require it

Comment: @Uzbekjon - any ideas on how I can try to solve this problem? Thanks again